# Activate macro automatically without having to click on target cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that hides certain rows when the values in a cell change. However this macro is not running unless you enter the target cell and click on it. I have tried several alternatives but none work for me.

*Sheet*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("$b$156").Value = 1 Then Call oculta_4
If Range("$b$156").Value = 2 Then Call oculta_5
If Range("$b$156").Value = 3 Then Call oculta_6
If Range("$b$156").Value = 4 Then Call oculta_7
End Sub
```

*Macro*

```
Sub oculta_4()
Rows("158:176").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Range("$c$158").Select
For Each celda In Range("$c$158:$c$176")
If celda.Value = 0 Then
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the values changed in the target cell by formula?

Comment: The worksheet_change event, will always kick in when you physically change a value on the sheet, but as mentioned earlier, it will not kick in, if the value of a cell is changed by a formula. You can use the worksheet_calculate event for that.

Comment: Effectively the value of the target cell changes with a formula

Comment: Then use Worksheet_Calculate not Worksheet_Change.

Comment: It's not working. Try this code but it doesn't run.                        
    Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    sheets("Hoja1").Select Range("$b$156").Select
    If Range("$b$156").Value = 1 Then Call oculta_4
    If Range("$b$156").Value = 2 Then Call oculta_5
    If Range("$b$156").Value = 3 Then Call oculta_6
    If Range("$b$156").Value = 4 Then Call oculta_7
    End Sub

Comment: Do not select the sheet put the code in the sheet code of `Hoja1`

Comment: Try that first but if I don't specify the macro runs on another sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, to respond to a value changed by a Formula, you need to use `Worksheet_Calculate`.

As `Worksheet_Calculate` does not have a `Target` property, you need to create your own detection of certain cells changing.  Use a `Static` variable to track last value.

You should also declare all your other variables too.

Repeatedly referencing the same cell is slow and makes code more difficult to update.  Put it in a variable once, and access that

`Select Case` avoids the need to use many `If`'s

Don't use `Call`, it's unnecessary and obsolete.

Adding `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` will make your code snappy, without flicker

Writing the hidden state of a row takes a lot longer than reading it.  So only write it if you need to.

Something like this (put all this code in the code-behind your sheet (that's `Hoja1`, right?)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Static LastValue As Variant
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Me.Range("B156")

    If rng.Value2 <> LastValue Then
        LastValue = rng.Value2
        Select Case LastValue 
            Case 1: oculta_4
            Case 2: oculta_5
            Case 3: oculta_6
            Case 4: oculta_7
        End Select
    End If
End Sub


Sub oculta_4()
    Dim celda As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each celda In Me.Range("C158:C176")
        With celda.EntireRow
            If celda.Value = 0 Then
                If Not .Hidden Then .Hidden = True
            Else
                If .Hidden Then .Hidden = False
            End If
        End With
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```